# CSS parent position relative and child position absolute

Tags: css

Hello I'm using the Google MDL Framework with the getmdl-select from CreativeIT but I have an issue.

The select has "position:absolute;z-index:999" attributes and the parent has "position:relative"
But the select doesn't display outside the container if it is too small : https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTBDI.png
The select's elements should appear in the blue square but they are hidden behind the mdl-card.

How to prevent this behavior ?

Thanks

---

Here are the files :
Google mdl css file : http://pasted.co/b8ff155a
getmdl-select css file : http://pasted.co/c651769d

I think the issue comes from mdl-menu__container and mdl-card

Comment: Please add your code you have so far, so we can help you better.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely, the parent card element should have `overflow:visible` added to it.